# Let current logged in user to own shared folder/volume on host OS rather than the "root' while running docker run command

Tags: docker

I have two commands below to create shared folder/volume on host OS but the owner of the folder is always `root`. How can I get `ubuntu` (he current logged in user) to own it? As a result, the `data` folder in host OS should be owned by `ubuntu`, not `root`.

**The current host OS user**

```
ubuntu@linux:~$ id
uid=1000(ubuntu) gid=1000(ubuntu) groups=1000(ubuntu)
ubuntu@linux:~$ pwd
/home/ubuntu
```

**Docker**

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV user bentcoder

RUN useradd -m -d /home/${user} ${user} \
 && chown -R ${user} /home/${user}

USER ${user}

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

**Commands I try**

```
ubuntu@linux:~$ docker run -i -t -d -v `pwd`/data:/home/bentcoder/data --name con img
ubuntu@linux:~$ docker run -i -t -d -u `id -u` -v `pwd`/data:/home/bentcoder/data --name con img
ubuntu@linux:~$ docker run -i -t -d -u bentcoder -v `pwd`/data:/home/bentcoder/data --name con img
ubuntu@linux:~$ docker run -i -t -d -u ubuntu -v `pwd`/data:/home/bentcoder/data --name con img
```

**Host OS shared folder/volume**

```
ubuntu@linux:~$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Dec  2 14:00 data
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  147 Dec  2 13:26 Dockerfile
```

Taking out `USER ${user}` out from Dockerfile won't change the result.

Answer (score 1):

So I believe what's happening here, is you didn't have the `data/` folder in your current working directory already (You probably do now after running these commands though; so delete it).

When you spin up the container with `$(pwd)/data` it's creating it for you, and by the looks of it, doing that before setting your UID to `bentcoder`.

If you're going to specify that bind-mount, then be sure it actually exists first. If it does - then you're all set (Unless you actually created it with root as well; then it'll map correctly - but you won't be able to write to it), if it doesn't - then you'll see the issue you're running into.

You won't need to specify the `-u bentcoder` in the `docker run` command at all; that's just being verbose.

Also - you have a typo on your `ENV user` in the Dockerfile.

Comment: I can manually create the folder beforehand to solve the problem but I am trying to avoid manual process if possible.

Comment: @BentCoder You're mapping a folder that **doesn't exist**; that's just how it is.

Comment: So what you are saying is, there is absolutely no way of creating a folder on host OS and owning it as a specific user at run time with `docker run ..... -v /non-existent/folder:/gueest/folder ....` ? Also I don't see a typo with `ENV` - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env.

Comment: @BentCoder No, not that I'm aware of. Your typo is `betcoder` rather than `bentcoder`.

Comment: Got it! I'll keep this question open for a while to see if anybody else has some kind of input. Thanks for the info for now.